# sed with regular expression as a bash variable

Tags: bash, sed, environment-variables

We have an application that keeps some info in an encrypted file. To edit the file we have to put the text editor name in an environment variable in bash, for example, EDITOR=vi. Then we run the application and it opens the decrypted file in vi. I am trying to come up with a bash script that updates the encrypted file. The only solution that I can think of is passing sed command instead of vi to the EDITOR variable. It works perfectly for something like `EDITOR='sed -i s#aaaa#bbbb#'`.

Problem starts when I need space and regular expression. For example: `EDITOR='sed -i -r "s#^(\s*masterkey: )(.*)#\1xxxxx#"'`  which return error. I tried running the EDITOR in bash with `$EDITOR test.txt` and I can see the problem. It doesn't like double quotes and space between them so I added a backslash before the double quotes and \s instead of space. Now it says unterminated address regex. For several hours I googled and couldn't find any solution. I tried replacing single quotes with double quotes and vice versa and everything that I could find on the internet but no luck.

How can I escape and which characters should I escape here?

**Update:**
Maybe if I explain the whole situation somebody could suggest an alternative solution. There is an application written by Ruby and it is inside a container. Ruby application has a secret_key_base for production and we supposed to change the key with `EDITOR=vi rails credentials:edit --environment=production`. I don't know Ruby and google did not return any ruby solution for automation so I could only think about sending sed instead of vi to Ruby.

Comment: You know that `vim` has `vim -x`? `For several hours I googled` so why not just create a executable file?

Comment: @KamilCuk, Thank you for your comment but I am not trying to encrypt or decrypt a file. This is an application that does lots of stuff and keeps its token in an encrypted file. My job is to rotate the token monthly.

Comment: Also, the application is inside a docker container and I am not allowed to create a file there. I need to come up with a solution that works on the fly and put that in an ansible playbook.

Comment: `the application is inside a docker container and I am not allowed to create a file there` That is most probably invalid, you surely can create files in `/tmp`. `put that in an ansible playbook` sure - do it.  Please read [ask], please see [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). (No, I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: @KamilCuk Again thank you for putting time. I know that it is possible to create a file on a container. I said I am not allowed to do that because the container is in production.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I escape and which characters should I escape here?

That is not possible. Word splitting *on the result of expansion* cannot be escaped *from inside the result* of that expansion, it will always run. Note that filename expansion is also running over the result of the expansion.

Create an executable file with the script content and set EDITOR to it.

You could export a bash shell function, after some tries I got to:

```
myeditor() {
     sed -i -E 's#^(\s*masterkey: )(.*)#\1xxxxx#' "$@"
}
export -f myeditor
EDITOR='bash -c "$@" _ myeditor'
```